# sort a list without using .sort()

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

I'm trying to find a way to sort a list with looping correctly.

I have this so far:

```
def min_sorted(xs):
    Min= xs[0]
    minsorted= list()
    for x in xs:
        if x < (Min):
            Min= x
            minsorted.append(Min)
            remove_val_once(x,xs)
    return minsorted
```

When i test it using `xs=[5,3,4,2,1]` this is what comes:

```
>>> min_sorted([5,3,4,2,1])
[3, 2, 1]
```

What is happening to the 5 and 4

my code for minval(xs):

```
def minval(xs):
min_= xs[0]
for x in xs[1:]:
    if x < min_:
        min_=x      
return min_
```

my code for remove_val_once:

```
def remove_val_once(val,xs):
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if val==xs[i]:
            del(val)
            return True
            break
    if val!=xs[i]:
        return False
```

Comment: What's the definition of `remove_val_once`?

Comment: What does `remove_val_once()` do? And look closely what happens to the first value for `Min`; you never do anything with that.

Comment: You can't sort an array with a single loop. The best you can do is in O(n log n) time.

Comment: remove_val_once is a function I defined that removes the first instance of x in xs @jwodder

Comment: Also, when you *remove* elements from a loop *during iteration*, the loop iteration pointer is not adjusted. if you first look at the first element, remove it, then the third element is now the second element, the second is now first **and is skipped** as the loop moves to process the second element of this altered list.

Comment: @user2829177: I think you need to completely rethink your algorithm.  Try working out the evaluation of `min_sorted` on paper and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: @user2829177 Why not implement a standard in place sorting algorithm? bubble sort to begin with?

Comment: Congratulations! you've invented a sorting algorithm that doesn't work! :)

Comment: I will continue working on my algorithm I guess! It seemed simpler to me but I guess not

Answer (score 3):

First of all: your algorithm is fundamentally flawed; you cannot sort the list this way.

You are going to skip elements as you process the list, for two reasons:

1. You discard the previous value of `Min` without ever appending it. This is why you skip `5`.
2. You are altering the list *while iterating*. When processing `3`, you remove it from the list. The loop was looking at the second item in the list, but removing `3` alters the list from `[5, 3, 4, 2, 1]` to `[5, 4, 2, 1]` after which the loop continues to the *third* item, now `2`. You skipped `4` there.

As to why your algorithm won't work: think about how your algorithm would handle a list with the smallest value already at start, like `[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're manipulating the list xs inside the loop, this makes your loop behave in strange ways. I suggest copying the xs into a temporary list and manipulating that. See code :

```
def min_sorted(xs):
    Min= xs[0]
    minsorted= list()
    t = xs[:]
    while t:
        Min = min(t)
        minsorted.append(Min)
        remove_val_once(t,Min)
    return minsorted
```

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, because the min function itself is O(n) and we're looping through the original input list.

There is also a bug in your `remove_val_once`, your use of `del` is wrong. It should be like this :

```
del xs[i]
```

Comment: This would just return the least number

Comment: You may as well use a `while xs:` loop if you are going to use `min()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: point taken, code edited. The OP didn't say if min is taboo or not

Comment: @user2829177 : this code is taking min out of t, then that is removed from t. In the next iteration of the loop, t will have one less element and a different min will be returned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: not sure what you mean by manipulating the wrong list. I tested the code before posting here, it works. I agree that we can sort without using t, but I'm trying not to change the OP's code too much. One could simply copy-paste bubble/insertion/radix or any other sort, but that wouldn't provide me the brain massage I seek in stackoverlow

Comment: Much better :-) Do add an explanation that this is a O(N^2) algorithm however; each `min()` loops through what is left of `t` each time.

Comment: I've defined the function minval(xs) for finding the minimum value of a list. so I can use that. however, if I test your code it doesnt return anything @Raiyan

Comment: @user2829177 can you please also post the code for minvals(xs) ? then I could test it on my computer and get back to you ? Thanks.

Comment: @Raiyan it's been added to my question

Comment: Just tested your code, @user2829177. There is a bug in remove_val_once which causes your program to enter an infinite loop. See my answer now for details.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 and 4 are being discarded by your "sorting" algorithm.  All your code does is take the first element of `xs` that is smaller than `xs[0]`, then the next element of the list that is smaller than that, then the next element smaller than that, and so on to the end of the list; it never does anything with the values that are skipped over.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Quicksort which is n log n (very fast).  It is a divide on conquer algorithm and I feel its very simple to remember the steps.

```
def qsort(arr):
  if len(arr) <= 1: return arr
  pivot = arr[0]
  left = []; right = []
  for i in arr[1:]:
    if arr[i] < pivot: left.append(i)
    else: right.append(i)
  return qsort(left) + [pivot] + qsort(right)
```

Pseudo Code:

- Base case.
- Select pivot.
- Divide left and right excluding pivot.
- Return qsort(left) + [pivot] + qsort(right)

Answer (score 0):

```
def min_sorted(values):
    result = []
    while values:
        m = min(values)
        result.append(m)
        values.remove(m)
    return result
```

Comment: I hardly think you should use a min() function when manually implementing a sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

there are easier ways to sort without using .sort(). I present to you insertion sort:

```
def insertionSort(unsortedList):
    # copy list
    length = len(unsortedList)
    sortedList = [None] * length
    for i in range(length):
    sortedList[i] = unsortedList[i];
    for i in range(1, length):
        j = i-1
        value = sortedList[i]
        while j >= 0 and value < sortedList[j]:
            sortedList[j+1] = sortedList[j]
            j = j-1
        sortedList[j+1] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, naive bubble sort:

```
import random

def bubble_sort(unsorted):
    length = len(unsorted) - 1
    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if unsorted[i] > unsorted[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                unsorted[i], unsorted[i+1] = unsorted[i+1], unsorted[i]

li = [random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(20)]
bubble_sort(li)
print li
```

Comment: @Raiyan: You seriously down voted this because it was not quick sort vs bubble sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
def min_sorted(xs):
    for i in range(0, len(xs)):
        for j in range(1+i, len(xs)):
            if xs[i] > xs[j]:
                temp = xs[i]
                xs[i] = xs[j]
                xs[j] = temp
    return xs
print("sorted list : ", min_sorted([5, 3, 4, 2, 1]))
```